# Isn't possible to create an instance of Page Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Simple WebForm.aspx class:

```
namespace _WebApplication
{
     public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
     {

     }

     public class TestClass : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
         WebForm1 webForm1 = new WebForm1();

     }
}
```

Inside the `TestClass` or any other class, it looks it lets me create the instance but doesn't let me use it. Code above doesn't give compile time error. But, if I type `webForm1`, it says it is a field but used like a type. I am asking the question cos I am just wondering.

Comment: It let you use it so your compile time error is related to something which you haven't shown. But you cannot use this `Page` anyway since it's not created in a real page's lifecycle. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: There's nothing else I have. Empty project. What do you mean by it's not created in a real page's lifecycle? A bit more detail please.. or link..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx Why do you want to create an ASP.NET  `Page` programmatically at all? That won't work. Tell us what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: Coming from C++. Wondering how wouldn't be possible to create an instance of a class and use it inside another class? thanks for the link

Comment: @Jude Don't mess with asp.net `Page` class to learn about `class`.

Comment: @Yair I want to know what really happens backthere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you merely derives from the `Page` class, it is not really meaningful & useful because the `Page` content and state ***is*** depends on the client HTTP request/post information which was sent to the server. the `Page` instance is initialized in a number of steps that the [**Page Life-Cycle**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) represents perfectly.

If you'll take a look at the `Page` class, you will be able to see that it contains properties and events which are related to the current client's request/page life-cycle, for example:

- **Request** Gets the HttpRequest object for the requested page.
- **Session** Gets the current Session object provided by ASP.NET
- **User** Gets information about the user making the page request

Look at the following flow diagram and notice how it is necessary for the `Page` to be "built" through its life-cycle process in order for the completion of the object/page:

[image]

Comment: Any other built-in class which works like this? We cannot or should not use the instance of it.

Comment: @Jude In the context of ASP.NET MVC, the `Controller` is such a `class`.

Comment: While your answer is in general correct one can in fact create an instance of an ASP.NET page and have useful applications of this. For example several years ago we were using AJAX enabled WCF services to send pieces of HTML to the client. The way we did it was to instantiate a page with a control and force it to render into a string and then send the string to the client to work with. There are much better ways to do that now but in the times when there were no client templates and/or Web API it made sense. A similar usage may be if you are preparing HTML for an e-mail.

Comment: @Stilgar What you mentioned is really good and make sense when the user don't have any intensive interaction with the page and all he can is to see it only (static). Eventually the `Page` is a class which you can render and convert to HTML but it is not its main purpose.

Comment: Yes there can be no postbacks. In our particular case the user could interact with the page but it was only via AJAX. We also used the same controls to render server-side pages for initial loading.

Comment: Well, nice utilization and haress of the `Page` class.